# Removing missing values for one specific column?

Tags: r

I want to specify that a select column has no missing values. Any other column can have missing values except this one. The column I will call 'Iteration'. Here is my code:

```
df = na.omit(df, cols = "Iteration")
```

This is a column of strings (ex: different division names for my dataset).

This returns an empty dataframe for some reason. Can someone catch my mistake?

Comment: we would need to see `df`.  Please include a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `df <- df[complete.cases(df$Iteration),]`

Comment: @Ryan This solution worked perfectly thank you so much! I am new to R so I think complete cases function is what I will be using to deal with missing values.